# Draw horizontal line in pdf using itext 5.0.6

Tags: android, pdf, line, itext

1. Can anyone tell me how to draw a horizontal line in pdf using itext 5.0.6?
2. This may be sounds strange when I capture a photo from camera and then I crop it. After that I display the cropped image but the below part of image has been cut (not the whole part cut but the some portion of the image has been cut approx. 2 to 3 horizontal line). How to fix it ?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [LineSeparator](http://api.itextpdf.com/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/draw/LineSeparator.html).

Note that it doesn't take up any space on the page.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand the problem you're having.  Could you be cropping it too much?

Comment: No.not too much but some of the portion from the below .Hope u can understand it......

Comment: I'm afraid not... Could you share your PDF?

Comment: @Bhavik, Consider accepting Mark's answer. And repost your second question separately and more precisely and perhaps it'll be answered as well.